# No response with Dropzone.js vdropzone-success () using chunked uploads

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js with Vue. I'm trying to hook in to the server response using v-on:vdropzone-success. Everything works as expected if the uploadFile is a single chunk but if there are multiple chunks the response comes back empty.Has anyone solved this issue? Am I missing something obvious? Thank you!

```
<dropzone   ref="myVueDropzone" 
                    id="customdropzone" 
                    :options="dropzoneOptions"
                    v-on:vdropzone-file-added="addFileTypeBorder"
                    v-on:vdropzone-upload-progress="updateProgressBar"
                    v-on:vdropzone-removed-file="removeFile"
                    v-on:vdropzone-success="addAnalysisId"
                    :include-styling="false">
        </dropzone>
```

Function:

```
addAnalysisId: function(file, response){
            console.log(response) 
        },
```

Here is what the server response looks like in my inspector. Each chunk is submitted as a separate request. The final request is shown. All other chunks respond with chunk #.
[Inspector image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Akh.png)

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue here. Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I see that is an old thread, but I bumped here looking for an answer. 
So looking in the library source code there is no second parameter returned on success. Only an instance of the file.

I found that in the returned object there is a xhr property. There you can find the response from the server. So in your case:

```
addAnalysisId: function(file){
        console.log(file.xhr.response); 
    },
```

You can then parse the response if needed and use it.

Answer (score 0):

for checking chunk's response you should add this code in dropzone.js:
(search "200" and you will find)

```
if (!(200 <= xhr.status && xhr.status < 300)) {
                this._handleUploadError(files, xhr, response);
            } else {
                if (files[0].upload.chunked) {
                    files[0].upload.finishedChunkUpload(this._getChunk(files[0], xhr));
                } else {
                    this._finished(files, response, e);
                }
            }
```

to :

```
if (!(200 <= xhr.status && xhr.status < 300)) {
                this._handleUploadError(files, xhr, response);
            } else {
                //check response
                var status=JSON.parse(response)['status'];
                if(status==='error'){
                    this._handleUploadError(files, xhr, response);
                } else {
                    if (files[0].upload.chunked) {
                        files[0].upload.finishedChunkUpload(this._getChunk(files[0], xhr));
                    } else {
                        this._finished(files, response, e);
                    }
                }
            }
```

_handleUploadError will upload failed chunks again.